# Codeigniter 4 Multiple Image Upload Issue

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-4

When I update the database, it uploads a single image. How do I upload multiple?

```
        $id = $this->request->getPost('id');
        
        $model = new UrunModel();
        $file = $this->request->getFile('resim');
        $resim_eski = $model->find($id);
        
        if($file->isValid() && !$file->hasMoved()){
        
        $eski_resim = $resim_eski['resim'];
        if(file_exists("dosyalar/uploads".$eski_resim)){
              unlink("dosyalar/uploads".$eski_resim);
        } 
        $imagename = $file->getRandomName();
        $file->move("dosyalar/uploads", $imagename);
        
        }else{
             $imagename = $resim_eski['resim'];
        }
        
        if ($this->request->getFileMultiple('images')) {
 
             foreach($this->request->getFileMultiple('images') as $res)
             {   
 
                $res->move(WRITEPATH . 'dosyalar/uploads');
             
        $data=[
        'baslik'          => $this->request->getPost('baslik'),
        'slug'            => mb_url_title($this->request->getPost('baslik'), '-', TRUE),
        'kisa_aciklama'   => $this->request->getPost('kisa_aciklama'),
        'kategori'        => $this->request->getPost('kategori'),
        'query_kategori'  => $this->request->getPost('query_kategori'),
        'aciklama'        => $this->request->getPost('aciklama'),
        'fiyat'           => $this->request->getPost('fiyat'),
        'indirimli_fiyat' => $this->request->getPost('indirimli_fiyat'),
        'resim'        => $imagename, 
        'resimler' =>  $res->getClientName(),
                'type'  => $res->getClientMimeType()
        ];
        
        
        $model -> update($id,$data);
        
        } 
        
        } 
        return redirect()->to(base_url('yonetim/urunler'));
        }
```

Controller code above, I've been struggling for 2 days, I couldn't manage it somehow.
When I run the code, it just adds 1 image to each product. I want to add more than one image to 1 product for the gallery part. Any suggestions for this code or a different solution?

Comment: without seeing your model and database structure (please add minimal example), it looks like that `$data` is constantly updating the row of `$id` in `$model -> update($id,$data);`. You always will see only the last image entry... BUT this is just a guess, while not seeing more details

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. There is no extra code in the model.

Comment: yes sure, no extra code, but anyway you are always overwriting(updating) your row with key $id. See: *update() - Updates an existing record in the database. The first parameter is the $primaryKey of the record to update. An associative array of data is passed into this method as the second parameter. The array’s keys must match the name of the columns in a $table, while the array’s values are the values to save for that key*, see [Saving data - update()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html?highlight=update#update)

Comment: The code is working. It just doesn't add multiple images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        function add()
      {
        $length = count($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $tempname = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

        $allimage = array();
        foreach($filename as $key =>$value)
        {
            move_uploaded_file($tempname[$key],'media/uploads/mobile_product/'.$filename[$key]);
            $allimage[] = $filename[$key];
        }
        if(!empty($allimage))
        {
            $allimage = json_encode($allimage);
        }
        else
        {
            $allimage = '';
        }

        $data['image'] = $allimage;
        $this->db->insert('table',$data);  

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CI4 Controller: 

  if($this->request->getFileMultiple('image_files')) {
        $files = $this->request->getFileMultiple('image_files');
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                if ($file->isValid() && ! $file->hasMoved())
                {
                    $newNames = $file->getRandomName();
                    $imageFiles = array(
                        'filename' => $newNames
                    );
                    $modelName->insert($imageFiles );
                    $file->move('uploads/', $newNames);
                }
            }
         }
HTML
<input type="file" name="image_files[]">
```

This is the shortest way to do that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).